# How would I implement a ranking algorithm in my website to sort database data?

Tags: python, sql, algorithm, implementation

I want to implement a ranking system on a website I've been working on and have decided to go with the Hacker News algorithm. My reasoning for choosing this algorithm is simply because it's been described [here](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574).

I was looking at this Python code (the language I'm using to build my site) and couldn't figure out how I would implement it.

```
def calculate_score(votes, item_hour_age, gravity=1.8):
    return (votes - 1) / pow((item_hour_age+2), gravity)
```

Given the tables:

```
posts:
    id | title | time_submitted

votes:
    id | postid | userid | score
```

How would I pull the data from the database? The ideal solution (most efficient) would be to construct a MySQL query to retrieve the top 10 posts ranked using the algorithm. But given that Hacker News has it implemented in Arc, it makes me think they pull out all the posts then run them through the algorithm to rank them.

Reddit also comes to mind for this... They use a non-relational database schema so I would assume they, like Hacker News, perform the rankings in their code - not the database.

How would you implement this?

**EDIT:** one post can have many votes as I would like to log which user votes on which post.

Comment: Is posts to votes a one to many relationship?

Comment: Yes. I just edited my post to explain why.

Comment: Um.. doing this in python would be pretty bad as far as performance and coding practice goes because you would have to retrieve all posts and votes and compare them. SQL can do this much faster and return only the data you need...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the data you need in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.time_submitted, SUM(v.score) as num_votes 
  FROM posts p, votes v
 WHERE v.postid = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY 
   (SUM(v.score) - 1) / POW(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,p.time_submitted,NOW()) + INTERVAL 2 HOUR, 1.8) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Pretty straight forward query, cheers! I'll have a play with it. Out of curiosity, have you any idea why Hacker News would use Arc instead of SQL? How would Reddit rank their items in the non-relation schema?

Comment: I tried running your query and got the error `syntax error near HOURS, 1.8)`. I'm not too familiar with the functions you're using but a bit of Googleing showed me to change it to `INTERVAL 2 HOUR` instead of `INTERVAL 2 HOURS`. Is this correct?

Comment: Is this at all scalable though? I feel like it would get very slow very fast

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the number of votes would be returned by:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM votes WHERE postid=<THE POST'S ID>;
```

If you want to consider score, you could include that in the query but the formula you provided is not equipped to handle it.

The item hour age is simply the current time subtracted from the time submitted:

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), time_submitted)) FROM posts WHERE id=<THE POST'S ID>;
```

This can also be done entirely in SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM posts ORDER BY (((SELECT count(*) FROM votes WHERE postid=posts.id) - 1) / MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), time_submitted) + INTERVAL 2 HOURS), <GRAVITY>)) LIMIT 10;
```